# jaxb too slow when parsing large file on servicemix

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to parse an xml file containing 100000 lines

schéma like :

```
<RplyColl ...>
     <Rply>
            ....
     </Rply>
</RplyColl>
<EnvColl>
    <Env>
        ...
    </Env>
</EnvColl>
<FpdColl rowID="73">
    <Fpd>
        ...
    </Fpd>
</FpdColl>
```

I parse the file like this:

```
        final Unmarshaller unMarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.context", ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader()).createUnmarshaller();
        object=  unMarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(new String(message.getBytes(), "UTF-8"))));
```

I'm using servicemix with jaxb-impl

```
  90] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] JAXB2 Basics - Runtime (0.6.4)
[  91] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jaxb-impl (2.2.11.1)
```

So when i'm going in debug mode i see my jaxbcontext is :

```
bundle://91.0:1/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 2.2.11
Classes known to this context:
...
...
```

After this, the unmarshall method call take 3minutes30sec :(

I try this code in Unit test and it take 10seconds,

Here is the jaxbcontext class to compare:

```
jar:file:/D:/maven/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 2.2.11
Classes known to this context:
[B
...
...
```

So why my servicemix take 3minutes30seconds and my unit test take only 10 seconds during unmarshall operation?

Does i miss something?

thank you very much

**VERSION**

jaxb-impl 2.2.11

servicemix :5.5.2

Answer (score 0):

finally i found my answer:

in servicemix someone change the value of :

```
org.apache.servicemix.specs.timeout=100
```

i change it to :

```
org.apache.servicemix.specs.timeout=0
```

and now it rocks!